# How to convert UNICODE Indic Characters (Brahmi and its descendents) to ISCII encoding?

Tags: unicode, character-encoding, iscii

I'm looking for some help with conversion of Indian language characters encoded in Unicode to ISCII(Indian Standard Code for Information Interchange). Going through the following link : http://www.unicode.org/faq/indic.html I was able to gain some understanding as to the differences between Unicode and ISCII but I've been unable to find information as to how to actually convert Unicode to ISCII programmatically.

An algorithm or flowchart for the same would also be helpful.

EDIT:

I'm working towards this in order to support printing of Indian languages through dot matrix printers (with ISCII encoding support). It is a win32 application written in C++ that feeds the printer with data.

Comment: The way to implement character code conversions depends on the programming language used, on the programming utilities available, and on the character codes. In general, there is no way to convert Unicode to ISCII, since the vast majority of Unicode characters have no representation in ISCII. So you would need to define what you mean by “conversion”, i.e. what should happen to characters that are not representable in ISCII.

Comment: The language i will be using is C++. Also, post conversion to ISCII i wish to send that data to a Dot Matrix printer (which supports ISCII encoding).

Comment: OK i've found this function WideChartoMultiByte in win32 with provisions for converting to ISCII.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually whatever system you are using likely has ISCII built-in as an encoding you can convert to or from. E.g. in .NET:

```
PS Home:\> [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncodings() | where name -like *iscii*

CodePage Name       DisplayName
-------- ----       -----------
   57002 x-iscii-de ISCII Devanagari
   57003 x-iscii-be ISCII Bengali
   57004 x-iscii-ta ISCII Tamil
   57005 x-iscii-te ISCII Telugu
   57006 x-iscii-as ISCII Assamese
   57007 x-iscii-or ISCII Oriya
   57008 x-iscii-ka ISCII Kannada
   57009 x-iscii-ma ISCII Malayalam
   57010 x-iscii-gu ISCII Gujarati
   57011 x-iscii-pa ISCII Punjabi
```

Which means, to convert to ISCII, you can just use the usual method of converting into any encoding, which in C# would be

```
var iscii = Encoding.GetEncoding("x-iscii-de");
var bytes = iscii.GetBytes(myString);
```

Java would have a similar mechanism, `iconv` as well. That's the general approach for environments that use Unicode natively.